# UINavigationBar only calling some delegates

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6, delegates

I'm adding a `UINavigationItem` with a save button to the right side, and a back button on the left side to my `UINavigationBar`. I am setting my view controller to be the delegate, and the navigation bar is calling some delegate functions, but not `-(BOOL)navigationBar:(UINavigationBar *)navigationBar shouldPopItem:(UINavigationItem *)item`.

In ISStudioReviewViewController.h:

```
@interface ISStudioReviewViewController : UIViewController <UINavigationBarDelegate, UITextViewDelegate>
    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UINavigationBar *header;
@end
```

In ISStudioReviewViewController.m:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    ...
    ...
    UINavigationItem *navHeader = [[UINavigationItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Compose Review"];
    [navHeader setHidesBackButton:NO];
    UIBarButtonItem *actionButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemSave
                                                                              target:self
                                                                              action:@selector(saveReview)];
    [navHeader setRightBarButtonItem:actionButton];
    [header setDelegate:self];
    [header pushNavigationItem:navHeader animated:NO];
}

-(BOOL)navigationBar:(UINavigationBar *)navigationBar shouldPopItem:(UINavigationItem *)item
{
    NSLog(@"Popping item");
    ....
    return YES;
}
-(BOOL)navigationBar:(UINavigationBar *)navigationBar shouldPushItem:(UINavigationItem *)item
{
    NSLog(@"Should push item");
    return YES;
}
-(void)navigationBar:(UINavigationBar *)navigationBar didPushItem:(UINavigationItem *)item
{
    NSLog(@"Pushing item!");
}
```

In my logs I can see that the shouldPush and didPush delegate methods are being called correctly, and my back button is being displayed. However clicking on the back button is not calling the delegate method, and `Popping item` is never logged.

I should note that the save button `actionButton` does properly call it's target without issue. I have tried not adding this button, and seeing if that is somehow causing the back button to fail, but no luck.

I am using ARC and targeting iOS 6.0.

Comment: I copied your code into a new app, and it worked fine for me -- I did get the "Popping item" log when I click the back button.

Answer (score 0):

The [Apple Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/NavigationControllers.html) states that you are not allowed to do this delegate.

> In addition, a navigation controller object automatically assigns itself as the delegate of its UINavigationBar object and prevents other objects from changing that relationship.

One/The? way to do what you want is to put in your own back-button.
In that Method you do your tests and call

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:true];
```

if the user is allowed to go back.